# SBT project navigation

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following build:

```
  lazy val stampleSearchProject = RootProject(file("../stample-search"))


  lazy val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
    .dependsOn(stampleSearchProject)
    .settings(defaultScalaSettings:_*)
    .settings( ......... )
```

The stample-search project has a build.sbt file with `name := "stample-search"`

I have found in the SBT documentation:

> Navigating projects interactively: 
>   At the sbt interactive prompt, type
>   projects to list your projects and project  to select a
>   current project. When you run a task like compile, it runs on the
>   current project. So you don't necessarily have to compile the root
>   project, you could compile only a subproject.

But the SBT documentation doesn't use RootProject but uses Project instead (which seems to require to use a project path inside the root project, I mean I can't use `../my-project`)

So I tried this.

```
[Stample] $ projects
[info] In file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/stample-web/
[info]   * Stample
[info] In file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/stample-search/
[info]     default-ccdbaa
```

So it seems to list both projects but I'd like to know where come this name `default-ccdbaa`

Then I try to use the project command

```
[Stample] $ project Stample
[info] Set current project to Stample (in build file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/stample-web/)

[Stample] $ project default-ccdbaa
[error] Invalid project name 'default-ccdbaa' in build file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/stample-web/ (type 'projects' to list available projects).

[Stample] $ project stample-search
[error] Invalid project name 'stample-search' in build file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/stample-web/ (type 'projects' to list available projects).
```

It doesn't seem to work. Can someone explain me what's wrong with my build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For details, you probably have to read [Full Configuration (Draft) : Project Relationships](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Dormant/Full-Configuration.html#project-relationships)

> There are three kinds of project relationships in sbt. These are described by execution, classpath, and configuration dependencies.
>   ...

`RootProject` defines a project reference, not a subproject. So you're effectively creating a source-level dependency, but you can't switch into it. A better approach would be to use plain [Multi-Project build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html).

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object HelloBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project(id = "hello",
                          base = file(".")) aggregate(foo, bar)

  lazy val foo = Project(id = "hello-foo",
                         base = file("foo"))

  lazy val bar = Project(id = "hello-bar",
                         base = file("bar"))
}
```

Comment: can you check this kind of related question please? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452142/sbt-does-not-want-to-enter-my-project-using-project-command