# SBT does not want to enter my project (using project command)

Tags: scala, sbt

My build is simple:

```
  lazy val stampleWebProject = play.Project("stample-web", appVersion, appDependencies,path = file("stample-web"))
    .dependsOn(stampleCoreProject,stampleSearchProject)
    .aggregate(stampleCoreProject,stampleSearchProject)

  lazy val stampleCoreProject = Project(id = "stample-core",base = file("stample-core"))

  lazy val stampleSearchProject = Project(id = "stample-search",base = file("stample-search"))
```

All these projects have a build.sbt file with dependencies, without any scala build (which would be ignored as far as I know)

When I start SBT (12.4), I get the following:

```
[info] Set current project to stample-core (in build file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/)

> projects
[info] In file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/
[info]   * stample-core
[info]     stample-search
[info]     stample-web

> project stample-search
[info] Set current project to stample-search (in build file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/)

> projects
[info] In file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/
[info]     stample-core
[info]   * stample-search
[info]     stample-web

> project stample-core
[info] Set current project to stample-core (in build file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/)

> projects
[info] In file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/
[info]   * stample-core
[info]     stample-search
[info]     stample-web

> project stample-web
[info] Set current project to stample-search (in build file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/)
[stample-search] $ projects
[info] In file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/
[info]     stample-core
[info]     stample-search
[info]   * stample-web

[stample-search] $ compile
[info] Updating {file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/}stample-core...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.6 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/home/sebastien/Bureau/Stample/}stample-web...
[error] a module is not authorized to depend on itself: stample-search#stample-search_2.10;1.0
[error] (stample-web/*:update) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: a module is not authorized to depend on itself: stample-search#stample-search_2.10;1.0
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 26 août 2013 21:57:45
```

I do not understand some stuff here:

- How is choosen the project in which we are by default. I've seem documentation was added in SBT 13.0 but did not see it in the 12.4 multibuild documentation.
- How comes I type project `stample-web` and it tells me I'm in `stample-search`
- Why is there a special display in my sbt console for the project I'm in (stample-web or stample-search, I don't really know...) (this appears here: `[stample-search] $ compile`, is this relative to play projects?
- Why it can't compile stample-search, since it doesn't depend on itself in my build (I suspect it tries to compile the web project but there's a naming problem or something?

Is this an SBT bug. If so, is it possible to use the new 13.0 version with Play framework?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue using sbt 0.12.4. Do you have any `*.sbt` files or `project` directory in `stample-web` or any other subprojects? They will get loaded, and might be messing things up. When you use `dependOn` you shouldn't have to use `aggregate`.

Comment: yes! you are absolutly right, I don't know how it came there but I have an unexpected sbt file in the stample-web folder, having `name := stample-search` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eugene Yokota is right: I have a conflict in the `stample-web` folder, which was set the stample-web name in the scala build, but it has a wrong build.sbt in the folder which has `name := stample-search`